# Getting the parameters values as null while working with custom wsdl file in axis2

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis

I have a web service method which takes a parameter. If I am not using any custom wsdl file, then it is working very fine. But it doesn't work when I use my custom wsdl file generated using axis2 code generation wizard in eclipse. I get the parameter value as null inside the web service method.
Please help me with this, as I have to use a custom wsdl file for this

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing a WSDL to describe your service and then use the generated AXIS2 methods for all the XML handling.

The following is an advanced example demonstrating exception handling, but it includes the same WSDL and associated service class code.

[Custom faultcode using Axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567452/custom-faultcode-using-axis2/)

Comment: You mean writing the wsdl manually, not to generate with the axis2 code generation wizard in eclipse? I found that both the auto generated wsdl file and the wizard generated wsdl file are same except the namespace prefix which is ns in auto-generated one and xsd in the wizard generated one. Please clarify little bit more how to write the custom wsdl.

Comment: The WSDL is the contract between you and the users of your service. They are not difficult to write. I've had poor experiences using WSDLs generated by various tools.... Such documents become impossible for humans to read and frequently it is impossible to understand the format of the SOAP message being exchanged.

Comment: ok. I will try to write one which will not give me any problem in passing parameters.. thank you for very much for ur help

Comment: Your welcome. If this answer helped please indicate this by accepting it. Unless of course someone else comes along with a better answer :-)