# Convention for Error/Failure response in SOAP with Axis2

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I have the following operation in my WSDL file:

```
<!-- mns stands for mynamespace -->
<operation name="Register">
    <input message="mns:RegisterRequest"/>
    <output message="mns:RegistrationNumber"/>
</operation>
```

I use the Axis code generator in Eclipse to generate a skeleton for this, and implemented it like this:

```
public class RegistrationServiceSkeleton
{
    public RegistrationNumber register(RegisterRequest registerRequest)
    {
        User user = User.register(registerRequest);
        if (user == null)
             // Registration failed, what to do?
             return null;
        RegistrationNumber registrationNumber = new RegistrationNumber();
        registrationNumber.setRegistrationNumber(user.getRegistrationNumber());
        return registrationNumber;
    }
}
```

For various reasons, the registration may fail. In this case, I want to return a faultstring like this:

```
<faultstring>Registration failed</faultstring>
```

I have a two questions.

(1) How do I do this in Axis2 (1.6.2) for Java?

(2) Is it a bad practice to do this, and if so, what is a best practice?

Comment: Hope this post will help to achieve your requirement.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567452/custom-faultcode-using-axis2

Comment: Ah, that looks very promising, thanks!